# Xamarin.Forms How to tell if an object is on screen

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I am trying to create a infinite scrolling grid image gallery that loads from a database.

Before I can even start I need to be able to tell what grid spaces to load images on. So how do I tell, efficiently, if a object is currently on screen? I can easily see a person loading a thousand images.

Comment: Typically you'd get the visible screen area as a rectangle, then you'd determine whether some or all of any given control is within this area. Have you started by looking at how to get the screen rectangle? Your question doesn't show a lot of research effort so is likely to get downvoted/closed.

Comment: If you use a Cell for your implementation there is a OnAppearing method to tell you when it will be on the screen. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.cell.onappearing?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Cell_OnAppearing